# Trigger function after reaching top of page the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run a function when the user hits the top of the page and is still scrolling top. However the function can not trigger, if user scrolls fast to the top of the page to reach the top of the current view. The function needs to work only if user insists to scrollTop. I am struggling with mouse wheel event, but it triggers many times, depending on how fast user has scrolled. Any ideas? My attempts below.

```
var scrolledTwice = false;

$('.js-films-listing').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
        scrolledTwice = true;
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            // upscroll code
            // do something if scrolledTwice
        } else {
            // downscroll code
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try onscroll listener.

Comment: After user scrolls to top of the page, onscroll event is not triggering anymore, because the page is not actually scrolling. I was trying to combine both, but mousewheel triggers always.

Comment: I think you need to look at debouncing the event. For events that repeatedly fire, there are methods to only register the last event fire.

Comment: @www139 could you please elaborate on this one? I experimented with some timeout but I have hit the wall. Is using timeout what you meant by debouncing? thanks

Comment: I'm actually writing an answer now....

Answer (score 1):

Note: if you are already at the top and continue to scroll up, wait a bit, and scroll up again, it will fire. Let me know if you want a scroll down to be a requirement before firing a scroll count. I.e., if you are at the top, scroll up, wait a bit, scroll up again, it will register two scrolls. You might consider adding a scroll down as a requirement before registering any additional scroll-ups.

Note the timeout. The timeout is used to debounce all the event fires. It will only increase the scroll count 100ms after the last scroll event was fired. Remember also that particular devices with "elastic" style scrollling will continue firing long after the scroll initally occurred. That's why I add a 100ms time delay. If a scroll fires under 100ms after the last one, the timeout is cancelled and restarted again.

A scroll up is registered when scroll top is 0. It's registered as a count flag which is reset after reaching two. There is an alert box after scroll top is reached twice.

```js
var scrollCount = 0;
var timeout;

$('.js-films-listing').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      scrollCount++;
      console.log(scrollCount);
    }
  }, 100);
  if(scrollCount == 2){
    alert('scrolled to top twice...restarting counter...');
    scrollCount = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
.js-films-listing {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-films-listing">
  <h1>testing</h1>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this code works, however is not suitable for my case. I needed Lethargy.js library to help me detect when user is actually trying to scroll.